# Dropdownlist onselectedindexchanged problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist like this

```
<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" autopostback="true" onselecteditemindexchanged="fire_event" ID="DDL"/>
```

and on codebehind i m doing this

```
page_load : if(!page.postback)I m binding data into dropdownlist
   fire_event: I am redirecting page to itemselected value.
```

So I am able to do most of the part everything is working perfectly except..

when i select item in dropdown it redirects me to the page I wanted..but when i click back it remains at the same item selected value .I want it to be like that it loads again when i click back for e.g.

if my dropdown is like state `A`
and other items

```
A
B
C
D
```

when I select `D` it takes me to page `D` and when i click back 
it is at state `D` i want it to show `A` instead of `D`

Comment: I would love to see if somebody has a solution for this.  I personally don't have one, and think your stuck... but I'd be interested in reading any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the back button on many(though not necessarily all) browsers you are not hitting the server, you are retrieving a copy of the page that has been cached by the browser in it's last state.
To avoid this you will need to prevent your page from being cached so that it is retrieved from the server instead. Adding the following to your page load will certainly do the trick in IE. [Further investigation](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/10/15/two-important-differences-between-firefox-and-ie-caching/) has revealed that this can also be achieved in Firefox using the no-store attribute:

```
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    Response.Expires = -1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...As u said it is only for IE so in IE this thing is doing what I wanted but now response.redirect is not working properly bcoz of it.But anyways I am looking for some solution which can work with FF,IE both....

Comment: No its fine with IE actually i was using FF only...and didn't try my code earlier in IE ...my response.redirect is not working at all in IE but yah I checked it urs code is gud with IE..but if htere is any way which can work with both...

Comment: @AB - I've checked this again and have seen work with FF 3.x.x. What version of FF are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to ensure that the right value is selected when the document is loaded. The following code is with jquery but you can do the same with Microsoft Ajax...

```
$.ready(function() {
    $("#mySelect").val(''); // Set the default value to select here
});
```

Have a good day!

Comment: I don't wanna use jquery or Ajax for this...I wanna do this from codebehind (C#)...I know there shud be some way...just not getting it....anyways...Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Guillaume Roy - I initially tried using javascript to solve this but found that the script doesn't fire when you use the back button to retrieve the cached page in Firefox.

Comment: I tried the code above in firefox 3.5 and it worked... can you send me your code ?